# Uploading and deleting unused images

Tags: users, files

I have a custom form with manage file input where users can upload their profile images. Upload looks like this:

```
 $acc = user_load($state['user_id'], TRUE);

 // upload profile image
 if ($state['values']['image'] != '0') {

   //check if this file is already in use, if not, save new file
   $res = db_select('users', 'u')
       ->condition('uid', $state['user_id'], '=')
       ->fields('u', array('picture'))
       ->execute()
       ->fetchAssoc();

   if ($res['picture'] != $state['values']['image']) {

     $img = file_load($state['values']['image']);

     file_usage_add($img, 'user', 'user', $state['user_id']);

     $img->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
     $acc->picture = $img;
     file_save($img);

   }

 } else {
   $acc->picture = NULL;
 }

 user_save($acc);
```

This approach is piling up unused files if user's change their images multiple times. It is because of `file_usage_add` function that is logging  files in database, therefore drupal won't delete files that are logged in `file_managed` database.

I think I could manually change old file status in database before new log is inserted by `file_usage_add` and let Drupal automatically remove this unused file. **Is this statement right?**

Even if it is true, I have strong feeling this is not optimal Drupal way of managing files. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by using [Audit Files](https://www.drupal.org/project/auditfiles) module.

> Audit files is designed to perform audits of your upload directory and
>   the corresponding database records. It will cross check that all files
>   in the database have a corresponding physical file, or it will check
>   that all files in the upload directory have a corresponding entry in
>   the database.

Comment: Thx, but this won't solve my problem. Files in database do have a corresponding physical file and all files in the upload directory do have a corresponding entry in the database

Comment: They'll be deleted on a cron job though, unless you've marked them as `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT`. Make sure that doesn't happen until a form submission, rather than validation, and you shouldn't have any problems. Same with file usage - don't update that until you're positive the file should be kept. That's how core image fields work and they don't have this issue